# MySQL two selects in one select in order

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have the following MySQL select statements:

```
SELECT * FROM tableX WHERE y_column > 10 AND Z = 200 LIMIT 100;
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM tableX WHERE Z = 200 y_column <= 10 LIMIT 100;
```

Suppose also that it is possible that I have more than 100 records in *tableX* that return a match for each statement. I want to execute the first statement before the second statement and have both of the statements return a result set that has a size <= 100.

Is it possible to write this in one MySQL statement?

Comment: Yes, perfectly possible. But note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is a fairly meaningless concept

Answer (score 0):

What I went with was something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM tableX WHERE ORDER BY y_column DESC LIMIT 100;
```